# Check if line Index was changed in edit control

Tags: winapi, controls, edit

Can i know or create a message which tells if the cursor moved to up or down a line in edit control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want a rich edit control to get a message for that, EN_SELCHANGE notification.  EM_GETSEL and EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR to map the caret position to a line number.